# Recipe Compile Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

New to posting here... and to using Chef... but I'm making a simple node slave cookbook and continue to get this error on every cookbook I make. I've searched and searched for help, but can't seem to find any insight on this issue anywhere... any help or advice is truly appreciated!

`Installing Cookbook Gems:
       Compiling Cookbooks...

```
   ================================================================================
   Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/attributes/default.rb
   ================================================================================

   NoMethodError
   -------------
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

   Cookbook Trace:
   ---------------
     /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/attributes/default.rb:6:in `from_file'

   Relevant File Content:
   ----------------------
   /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/attributes/default.rb:

     1:  default['jenkins']['user'] = 'jenkins'
     2:  default['jenkins']['group'] = 'jenkins'
     3:  default['jenkins']['home'] = '/home/jenkins'
     4:  default['jenkins']['work_dir'] = '/opt/jenkins'
     5:  
     6>> if node['tomcat']['base_version'] > 6
     7:    default['jenkins']['tomcat_service'] = 'tomcat'
     8:    default['jenkins']['install_dir'] = '/usr/share/tomcat/webapps'
     9:  else
    10:    default['jenkins']['tomcat_service'] = "tomcat#{node['tomcat']['base_version']}"
    11:    default['jenkins']['install_dir'] = "/usr/share/tomcat#{node['tomcat']['base_version']}/webapps"
    12:  end
    13:  default['jenkins']['build_dependencies'] = []
    14:  default['jenkins']['versioned_packages'] = []
    15:  # Example:

   Platform:
   ---------
   x86_64-linux


   Running handlers:
   [2016-10-14T22:58:04+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
   Running handlers complete
   [2016-10-14T22:58:04+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
   Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 22 seconds
   [2016-10-14T22:58:04+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
   [2016-10-14T22:58:04+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
   [2016-10-14T22:58:04+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
   [2016-10-14T22:58:05+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)`
```

I am required by my work to run this version of Chef:

`Chef Development Kit Version: 0.15.16
chef-client version: 12.11.18
delivery version: master (444effdf9c81908795e88157f01cd667a6c43b5f)
berks version: 4.3.5
kitchen version: 1.10.0`

Answer (score 0):

`node['tomcat']` is unset so you can't use values below it. This probably means you missed a dependency in your `metadata.rb` file.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. I was very perplexed since a few coworkers were able to make the same cookbooks work without having that line in their metadata files.

Comment: Node attributes are global so if the the tomcat cookbook was pulled in either via a run list or something else depending on it, it would get loaded.